# android main XML works diffrent on 2.3 and 4.0

Tags: android, layout

this XML works different on 2.3 and 4.0. one of that shows table row elemens left fitted but other centered.

thanks for your help

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Scorelistic"  android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/bestscore" android:layout_height="267dp" android:layout_width="432dp" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">

            <TableLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TableRow android:layout_height="85dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="349dp" android:layout_height="74dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                        <ImageView android:layout_height="74dp" android:id="@+id/score1" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="349dp" android:background="@drawable/birincibg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/birinci" android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </TableRow>         
              </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be because you're specifying device points and so the whole layout becomes dependent on your device screen size. And so if your two devices have different screen sizes you  see the difference. It's generally not recommended to use device points in layouts you may want to use gravity, alignments and weights instead. Especially in TableLayouts you don't really need device points or so it seems

Comment: so how can I put the ImageView before TextView without margin? also I didn't give that minus point..

Comment: I think, instead of specifying layout_height and layout_width in dp you should specify them like wrap_content or fill_parent and with weights as applicable. The margins then you can specify by using, say android:paddingLeft within your element. Who gave minus should come with a better solution.